# `ArguementException` in `FileSystemWatcher`

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I was just testing the functionality of `FileSystemWatcher` when I got `ArguementException` on this line

```
    fileSystemWatcher1.Path = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer.ToString() ;
```

Why is this error coming, if the given path is valid.
`The directory name MyComputer is invalid.`

Comment: What folder are you trying to watch? Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer is just telling you what MyComputer is called in your language.

Comment: I want to watch all the drives.

Comment: Then you have to create one FileSystemWatcher for c:\, d:\ etc.

Comment: Which is probably not something you want to do. This will be an extremely heavy operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an enumeration.  When you call `.ToString()` on an `enum` value, you get the string representation of that `enum` value - literally `MyComputer` in this case.  If you want to get the location of the `MyComputer` folder, you want to use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

However, `MyComputer` will return an empty string, so you still can't use it in the way you're attempting.

Answer (score 2):

> "I want to watch all the drives."

I'm not sure that you will be able to implement the FileSystemWatcher in a way that is global for all connected storage in this way.

"MyComputer" is not a physical location and so can not be used as an entry point in the way described.

Answer (score 1):

If you really REALLY want to watch all files on all drives you can do something like this:

```
        var w = Environment.GetLogicalDrives().Select(path => new FileSystemWatcher(path)).ToList();

        foreach (var watcher in w)
        {
            watcher.Changed+=watcher_Changed;
        }
```

Where the watcher_Changed is the event handler for each of the FileSystemWatchers.

Comment: Though this is *technically* a solution, it really makes me shutter.